# Prolog Find All Predicate

Tags: recursion, prolog, artificial-intelligence, prolog-setof

I am trying to find all the brothers of a person.. I have created the following rule..

```
    find_all_brothers(Z):- findall(X,brother(X,Z),X0),write(X0).
```

This works however, if a person has more then one brother then it will only find a single brother.. I'm assuming I have to use recursion somehow but I'm a little stuck!

Comment: `findall` will find all of them. Can you show what your prolog facts look like for `brother`?

Comment: Will it!? Oh dear haha! Ok Ill add them up now thanks! :)

Comment: Well, depending... see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have relationships such as:

```
brother(sam, bill).
brother(bill, fred).
```

And you want to find all of bill's brothers, you'll need to do a little more:

```
find_all_brothers(Z) :-
    findall(X, (brother(X, Z) ; brother(Z, X)), X0), write(X0).
```

To avoid any redundant members of the list, `setof` will sort and provide only unique members:

```
find_all_brothers(Z) :-
    setof(X, (brother(X, Z) ; brother(Z, X)), X0), write(X0).
```

Comment: @false yes, I considered `setof`. I wasn't sure if it was necessary in this case depending upon how the OPs facts and rules were set up. `setof` is certainly safer.

Comment: Is the order of solutions relevant? Are redundant solutions important? In those cases, `findall/3` would be OK. Otherwise `setof/3` is preferable, **even if** it fails for the case where the `Goal` fails.

Comment: Yep, those are good questions whose answers aren't necessarily clear from the original question.